# When will functions of two uncorrelated random variables be still uncorrelated?

Tags: probability

1. I wonder how to find examples of two uncorrelated random variables
   $X$ and $Y$ whose squared $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are correlated?
2. More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, when will $f(X)$
   and $f(Y)$  also be uncorrelated for some function $f$? I.e. what
   conditions on $f$, $X$ and $Y$? E.g.

   - I know when $X$ and $Y$ are
     independent, that is true for many $f$.
   - when $f$ is a linear function, $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ are still uncorrelated
   - ... (do you know other nontrivial/interesting cases?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Nearly everything works.

Example: $X$ uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Y=X-X^2$. Can you show that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated and that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are correlated?

Hint: For every $n$, $E(X^n)=1/(n+1)$.

(Your 2. is a typical example of a question with no answer.)

**Edit:** Another example, maybe simpler: $X$ symmetric around zero, say uniform on $(-1,1)$ or normal centered, and $Y=|X|$.

Comment: Thanks! The uniform example seems  carefully constructed, but it is also simple enough.