# does uncorrelation extend to product of complex random variables?

Tags: correlation

Give two uncorrelated complex variables, $X$ and $Y$. Are $XX^{*}$ and $YY^{*}$ also uncorrelated, where $*$ means complex conjugation?

Comment: How do you define uncorrelated for complex random variables? Something like $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ or $E[XY^*] = E[X]E[Y^*]$?

Comment: the second definition

Comment: This doesn't hold even for real random variables. For [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757505/when-will-functions-of-two-uncorrelated-random-variables-be-still-uncorrelated)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on distributions:

$$ Cov(|X|^2 , |Y|^2) = E[|X|^2 |Y|^2] -  E[|X|^2]E[ |Y|^2]$$

$$ E[|X|^2 |Y|^2] = \int_{x,y}|X|^2 |Y|^2\ f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy $$

Only, in case of **Gaussian** distribution we can say
$$  f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)  \ \ \ (1)$$

and therefor the co-variance is zero; they are uncorrelated

but, always (1) is true for independent random variables

so, in general the answer depends on distribution of X and Y

Comment: Thanks..very nice derivation. Looks like the uncorrelatedness of $|X|^2$ and $|Y|^2$ does not depend on the uncorrelatedness of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: It seems, but i am not totally certain ! since humane errors always exist

Comment: I think you are correct, looks like there is no way to use the uncorrelatedness of $X$ and $Y$ in $|X|^2$ and $|Y|^2$